# Reuse CSP script nonce throughout the session?

Tags: jsf, content-security-policy, nonce

This is a follow-up of https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/issues/215. [arturjanc](https://github.com/arturjanc) suggested to move this discussion to stackoverflow.

We are trying to implement CSP for scripts in JSF and don't know if it is safe to reuse a script nonce throughout the session. Or, like arturjanc suggested, have the original document send its current nonce to the server which generates future responses.

Assuming that it is unsafe to reuse the nonce throughout the session, would it be okay to just include the initial nonce in hidden form input like currently implemented [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/commit/c614e01cd4a5dca71487f5c0852478ddfd6a58dc). (ignoring the CSP header/XSS injection vulnerabilities for the moment - it's just a prototype)

@arturjanc: Would you like to chime in again?

Edit: Additional thoughts regarding arturjanc's answer:

Could you please elaborate a bit more on how to implement per-response nonces in a typical JSF application of nowadays, i.e. just having one single full page load at the very beginning and subsequent XHR-only communication?

If I understand you correctly, your suggestion would be then to always resend the initially generated nonce in every XHR request. However, in practice this is effectively the very same as nonces per session, isn't it? Just more complicated in terms of implementation.

Strictly implementing per-response nonces would imply that subsequent responses must also include all nonces created earlier in that session, so we would somehow track all nonces of the session.

Setting new CSP headers for each XHR-response containing only the newly created per-response nonce, would probably not work due to browsers treating multiple CSP headers across responses by merging them using an intersection strategy, i.e. `Content-Security-Policy: 'nonce-1'` in response 1 and `Content-Security-Policy: 'nonce-2'` in response 2 would render both nonces invalid after response 2.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no single correct answer to your questions: it's not obviously wrong to have a per-session nonce, but it introduces the risk that whenever a nonce can be leaked by an attacker it will be reusable on another page load, allowing the attacker to exploit an XSS bug that would otherwise be mitigated by CSP.

Specifically, when you include the nonce in a hidden input field, it allows the value to be exfiltrated by [abusing CSS selectors](https://www.mike-gualtieri.com/posts/stealing-data-with-css-attack-and-defense); note that the same attack would not work against the `script#nonce` attribute because the browser hides the value of that attribute from the DOM to protect against such attacks.

My recommendation would be two-fold:

- Try to make the nonce per-response rather than per session. This way even if the nonce can be exfiltrated, it will be difficult for an attacker to re-use it.
- If you need to re-use the nonce to allow asynchronously fetched markup from the server to contain scripts with the correct nonce value, do this without copying the nonce to the DOM. For example, if you use an XHR to a URL with a `nonce` parameter, do something like `xhr.open("/my/url?nonce=" + document.currentScript.nonce)`

Comment: Thanks, please see my additions to the original question regarding your suggestions. (Unfortunately, my answer is too long for stackoverflow's comments. Let's go back to github? ;-))

Comment: Unfortunately, my answer was too long for stackoverflow's comments. Let's go back to [github](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3505) to the concrete discussion on how to integrate CSP in JSF/PrimeFaces? ;-)

Comment: Not sure this is still active, but is there a good way to handle nonces when you have an app in which you want to allow multiple tabs open at once ?  I'm using PHP, and the nonce is regenerated on every page load, so the old nonce will no longer be valid.

Comment: The nonce requirement is enforced by the browser at the document level: if a given page has a CSP with a nonce, then `<script>` elements on that page will need to set that nonce, but other documents/tabs from your application will not be affected. 

So, by default, CSP nonces are compatible with multiple tabs -- the only thing your application needs to do is to make sure that for a given HTTP response `<script>` elements have the same nonce value as the one set in the CSP header delivered with that response.